meaning of "make proper change"
Does "make proper change" mean both to give proper change to customers and to receive proper change from store workers?
In the following quote,it seems to mean "to receive proper change" from staff in stores.

Another big area people may notice abnormal forgetfulness? Finances, according to Bernick.
That could be forgetting to pay bills, paying bills twice, not understanding how finances work or forgetting how to make proper change when paying for items in stores.


This is a highly unusual, one-off use of the phrase, and it seems unlikely that analysing it here would lead to any general insight into English language and usage. It is possible that some follow-up questions in comments would have led to the question being elaborated in some useful way, but given that the moderator has decided to make such exploration impossible, the only thing left to do is close the question.

In this context, “make proper change” refers to receiving the correct amount of change from store workers when paying for items. It implies ensuring that the change given is accurate and appropriate.

That's not how I read "forgetting how to make proper change when paying for items in stores". To me, it means not able to present the correct money, paying with a note (a bill), as Yosef's comment.

Like Weather Vane, I can't see how it can mean that here. But I can't see any justification for the way the quote uses it. Typical is "Can you make change for a twenty?" This means 'give the correct change if I tender a round sum in excess of the cost.'
